# Cities: Skylines. How can I block a road to all but city services (police, fire)

Tags: cities-skylines

Vanilla Cities:Skylines. I want to blockade all except city services from using a road.  Any way to do that?

My city's freight rail system is isolated from the international network, because our rails are broad gauge (actually so the network's [train jams](https://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/611701999518796593/) can't shut down my commerce).

So I have a "Freight Free Trade Zone" in my city [(as is often done)](https://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/78bazp/can_someone_explain_internal_cargo_trains_to_me/)... containing international freight container-ship and train terminals, and a domestic freight train terminal.  That is to force all external, rail or ship delivered freight onto my internal freight rail network.

I've made several passes at this, and it works quite well.

*(if trucks have direct access to one international freight terminal, it greatly increases town traffic and the backup at the freight terminal is literally over a mile long; I built out [stack roads](https://www.rte.ie/news/2020/1222/1185899-britain-covid-latest/) so I know.)*

**The problem is, these terminals require police, fire, medical and hearse services.  They also need trash hauled away**.

So... I'm looking for a way for those municipal vehicles to get road access *only they will use* and block all other vehicles.  That way I don't need to build a clinic, cop shop, fire station, etc. just for the trade zone.

*I have tried having having one road, routed through a District with a "No heavy trucks" policy.  All the trucks ignore it once they realize there's no other roadway route*.

Comment: I do not actually have an answer to your question, but I learned from Biffa City Fix (youtube) that traffic jams should be solved rather than worked around. Having industry combined at one location causes many trucks to block everything up, so his advise is, put your industry in small chunks all around your city, as well as other services such as waste, etc. If you design the traffic well, you should not need a dedicated road for emergency traffic at all.

Comment: yeah, I figured that one out too, after trying Traffic Manager to fix all the "one-lane crowding" problems which were *actually* exit/layout problems. However, access notwithstanding, the free trade zones/forcing traffic onto internal rail network has worked really well. I even disconnected my city so all external traffic had to come through the FTZ, and even that worked.  I just gave up and built fire stations etc.

Comment: Yeah. Sounds like the right approach. :) I've felt for the same trap myself many times before seeing Biffa's videos though.